# Corona function position inside events scene

Tags: function, coronasdk, scene

I created this simple game consisting of a ball going into a moving cointainer thanks to the gravity force. The problem concerns the container that should be moving to the right and to the left randomly thanks to the function called "***moveContainer***" , but it remains still. The container is made of 3 rectangles called bottomSide, leftSide and rightSide, created in the event *scene:create*.

As you can see I call that function inside the event *scene:show* but the container doesn't move. The game works perfectly without using scenes, so I guess the problem concerns the scene implementation.
Could you please check out my code and tell me what I'm doing wrong? It would mean a lot to me. Feel free to try my code in your editor.  Thanks!

```
local composer = require( "composer" )

local scene = composer.newScene()

-- -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
-- Code outside of the scene event functions below will only be executed ONCE unless
-- the scene is removed entirely (not recycled) via "composer.removeScene()"
-- -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------


local physics = require( "physics" )
physics.start()
physics.setGravity(0, 5 )
physics.setDrawMode( "normal" )


local left_side_piece
local center_piece
local right_side_piece

local obstacle
local rotation

local bottomSide
local leftSide
local rightSide

local lineCollision

local speed
local distance

local ball

--local fg
local fg = display.newGroup()


local line
local x
local y


local function moveContainer()
  speed = math.round(math.random(1700,2000))
  distance = math.round(math.random(50,display.contentWidth-50))
  transition.to(bottomSide,{time = speed, x =  distance, onComplete = moveBall})
    transition.to(leftSide,{time = speed, x =  distance-25})
    transition.to(rightSide,{time = speed, x =  distance+25})
    transition.to(lineCollision,{time = speed, x =  distance})
end




function draw(event)
    if event.phase=="began" then
        x = event.x
        y = event.y



    elseif event.phase=="moved" then
             line = display.newLine(fg, x,y,event.x,event.y)
             physics.addBody( line, "static", { radius=4 })
                 line.strokeWidth = 2
                 x = event.x
               y = event.y

    elseif event.phase=="ended" then
          physics.start( )
      timer.performWithDelay( 3000, bodyAwake,6 )


  end
end



local function bodyAwake()

  if(ball.isAwake== false)then
    local myText = display.newText( "RITENTA", 120, 30, native.systemFont, 16 )
    myText:setFillColor( 1, 0, 0 )
    setWorldChange = true
    transition.cancel()
    physics.pause()
  end
end



local function onLocalCollision( self, event )

    if ( event.phase == "began" ) then

            if ( self.myName == "sensore" and event.other.myName== "ball1" ) then
                local myText = display.newText( "PALLA ENTRATA", 120, 30, native.systemFont, 16 )
                myText:setFillColor( 1, 0, 0 )
        setWorldChange = true
                transition.cancel()


      elseif ( self.myName == "fondale" and event.other.myName== "ball1" ) then
                local myText = display.newText( "RITENTA", 120, 30, native.systemFont, 16 )
                myText:setFillColor( 1, 0, 0 )
        setWorldChange = true
                transition.cancel()
        physics.pause()

      end

    end
end



local function removeLine()
    if (setWorldChange == true) then
            for i = fg.numChildren, 1, -1 do
                 fg[i]:removeSelf()
                 fg[1] = nil
                 end
    setWorldChange = false
    end
end



local function updateBall()
  leftSide.x = bottomSide.x-25
    rightSide.x = bottomSide.x+25
    lineCollision.x = bottomSide.x

end
-- -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
-- Scene event functions
-- -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------

-- create()
function scene:create( event )

    local sceneGroup = self.view
    -- Code here runs when the scene is first created but has not yet appeared on screen
    physics.pause()

--  local fg = display.newGroup()
    sceneGroup:insert( fg )

    local left_side_piece = display.newRect( 0-5, display.contentHeight/2, 660, 10 )
    physics.addBody( left_side_piece, "static" )
    left_side_piece.rotation = 90

    local center_piece = display.newRect( display.contentCenterX, display.contentHeight+160, 400, 120 )
    physics.addBody( center_piece, "static" )
    center_piece.myName="fondale"    --se la pallina collide con fondo, si va a pagina di replay

    local right_side_piece = display.newRect( display.contentWidth+5, display.contentHeight/2, 660, 10 )
    physics.addBody( right_side_piece, "static" )
    right_side_piece.rotation = -90


    local obstacle = display.newRect( 150,300,50,50 )
    obstacle:setFillColor( 222.0/255.0, 184.0/255.0, 135.0/255.0 )
    physics.addBody( obstacle, "static" )
    obstacle.gravityScale = 0
    local rotation = transition.to(obstacle, {time=3000, rotation=-360, iterations=-1} )


    local bottomSide = display.newRect( 160, display.contentHeight, 50, 3 )
    physics.addBody( bottomSide, "static",{ density=1.0, friction=0.4, bounce=0.2} )
    local leftSide = display.newRect( 134, display.contentHeight-24, 50, 3 )
    physics.addBody( leftSide, "static" )
    leftSide.rotation = -90
    local rightSide = display.newRect( 185, display.contentHeight-24, 50, 3 )
    physics.addBody( rightSide, "static" )
    rightSide.rotation = -90



    local lineCollision = display.newRect( 160, display.contentHeight-10, 35, 2 )
    physics.addBody( lineCollision, "static", {isSensor=true} )
    lineCollision.myName = "sensore"

    local ball = display.newCircle( display.contentWidth/2, 0, 8 )
    ball:setFillColor( 1,0,0 )
    physics.addBody( ball, "dynamic", { density=2.0, friction=0.6, bounce=0, radius=8 } )
    ball.myName= "ball1"

  lineCollision.collision = onLocalCollision
  lineCollision:addEventListener( "collision" )

  center_piece.collision = onLocalCollision
  center_piece:addEventListener( "collision" )



end


-- show()
function scene:show( event )

    local sceneGroup = self.view
    local phase = event.phase

    if ( phase == "will" ) then
        -- Code here runs when the scene is still off screen (but is about to come on screen)
    elseif ( phase == "did" ) then
        -- Code here runs when the scene is entirely on screen
    physics.pause()
    moveContainer()


        Runtime:addEventListener("touch",draw)
    Runtime:addEventListener( "enterFrame", removeLine)
    --Runtime:addEventListener("enterFrame", updateBall)




    end
end


-- hide()
function scene:hide( event )

    local sceneGroup = self.view
    local phase = event.phase

    if ( phase == "will" ) then
        -- Code here runs when the scene is on screen (but is about to go off screen)

    elseif ( phase == "did" ) then
        -- Code here runs immediately after the scene goes entirely off screen
        physics.pause()

    end
end


-- destroy()
function scene:destroy( event )

    local sceneGroup = self.view
    -- Code here runs prior to the removal of scene's view

end


-- -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
-- Scene event function listeners
-- -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
scene:addEventListener( "create", scene )
scene:addEventListener( "show", scene )
scene:addEventListener( "hide", scene )
scene:addEventListener( "destroy", scene )
-- -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------

return scene
```

Answer (score 1):

Change declaration of `bottomSide`, `leftSide` and `rightSide` in `scene:create`function

```
-- I have removed local keyword
bottomSide = display.newRect( 160, display.contentHeight, 50, 3 )
...
leftSide = display.newRect( 134, display.contentHeight-24, 50, 3 )
...
rightSide = display.newRect( 185, display.contentHeight-24, 50, 3 )
```

Otherwise you create different variables with the same name.

See [Lua - Two local variables with the same name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16963768/lua-two-local-variables-with-the-same-name)

Have a nice day:)

Comment: You saved me!   One last problem and I'm done: in the "ended" phase of the function draw(), I set a timer.performWithDelay() that should call the function bodyAwake() every 3 seconds, but it doesn't work. Any tips in order to fix this?

Comment: I'm not sure but move body of `bodyAwake` function above `draw` function should solve problem. See [Forward define a function in Lua?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6067369/forward-define-a-function-in-lua) and [Lua: How to call a function prior to it being defined?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12291203/lua-how-to-call-a-function-prior-to-it-being-defined) for more information.